# omxPlayer playing HLS stream, volume doesn't change immediately in RaspberryPi

Tags: volume, rtmp, raspberry-pi2, omxplayer

In raspbian jessie i am using omxplayer to play a HLS stream from command line. when it plays video, any volume command given from keyboard/remote doesn't execute immediately rather it updates volume at the end of every .ts stream chunk i.e after every 9-10 sec.

is there any possible way to execute this volume immediately?